# Replace Column using ID in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

(Fairly new to SQL so please bear with me :) )
I have a table with two entries:

Table 1:

| ID | Owner | Donor | Sire | ET1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | Jones | Daisy | Bob | 18 |
| 18 | Owens | Daisy | Bob | 834 |

As you can see, the two entries share the same Donor and the same Sire. I also need them to share the same ET1 number. Currently, the first entry has an ET1 which is actually the ID of the second entry, but I need them both to share the same ET1. I used the following code, and it enters however it does not actually update any of the entries. I thought it would be simple but can someone shed some light on what I could be doing wrong?

```
update table1 t
set t.ET1 = t.ET1
where t.ET1 = t.ID
```

Comment: 'i need them to both to share the same ET1' - what's the logic for deciding which one?

Comment: `where t.ET1 = t.ID` is never true within a single row. `Where` only compares values within the individual row.

Comment: Basically if they share the same donor and sire they need to share the same ET1. The ET1 is our most important feature as that's how we identify records- we will always search for the ET1, but we may have done a change of ownership which means a new record is entered and only the owner changes. I'm looking for a query to help update the entries like the one above which is incorrect.

Comment: And `set t.ET1 = t.ET1` would just set the value to itself. Again `t` only refers to a single row at a time.

Comment: You must use 2 table copies in UPDATE at least. Really you must use recursive CTE in data source for updating, or create simple 2-table updating query and execute it until updated rows amount is zero.

Comment: `Basically if they share the same donor and sire they need to share the same ET1`...yes we know that already. but it's unclear, from the sample data, whether 18 or 834 should be considered the "correct" value, or how the computer should decide that.

Comment: PS. Your update will kill the information forever (but this info may make sense! in its historical part at least). I recommend you to create and fill additional column, like `RootET1`.

Comment: At a guess the earliest id is the correct et1 - but given names are not unique it would seem inappropriate to join on donor and sire..

Comment: @ADyson ah okay... i mean that makes alot of sense now you've mentioned it. How do i specifically state that 834 would be the correct value, without specifically stating so especially if i had a lot of data?

Comment: @P.Salmon in my actual table the donor and sire and owner are numbers relating to their ID in other tables. I used actual names for the sake of this demonstration :)

Comment: You need to define a general rule by which it can be calculated in any pair of rows. Also you need to define how a row is a pair - you say it's when donor and sire are the same, but presumably Daisy and Bob have created one than one offspring? So that's not unique enough. e.g. perhaps is it the case that when the E1 of row A equals the ID of row B, they are a pair, and then the ET1 of row B must be correct. Does that apply to all your data? Once you define the rule, we can work out how to represent that in code.

Comment: @ADyson right okay again, that makes sense. Yes this applies to not all but alot of my data in this table. I suppose the general rule is when row A's ET1 = row B's ID, they have the same donor and sire, but different owner.

Comment: Ok then. Untested, but this hopefully gives you the general idea: `UPDATE table1 t1 SET t1.ET1 = t2.ET1 FROM table1 t1 INNER JOIN table1 t2 ON t1.ET1 = t2.ID AND t1.Donor = t2.Donor AND t1.Sire = t2.Sire AND t1.Owner <> t2.Owner` . Basically you join the table to itself so you can match different rows within the same table based on the ET1/ID linkup, and then it's filtered by the additional criteria about owners/sires/donors. That may not work exactly as-is, I haven't tested the syntax etc but hopefully you see where it's going.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before doing the update, I strongly suggest these two precautions:

1. Backup the table - in case you update it wrong, you can recover from the backup.
2. Run a `SELECT` query before turning into `UPDATE` - to see what you'll be updating.

Additionally, I second @Akina's comment with adding a reference column for the original `ET1` or the updated `ET1`.

With that, let's look at this query:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 a 
  JOIN table1 b 
  ON a.Donor=b.Donor 
  AND a.Sire=b.Sire 
  AND a.ET1 > b.ET1;
```

`table1` in the query is self-joining with `ON` condition according to your requirement and I assume the smallest `ET1` value in that condition will be considered as the `ET1` value for any record having larger `ET1` (or larger ID?). This query will do just that and after confirming it with a `SELECT` query, simply change the query to the following:

```
UPDATE table1 a 
  JOIN table1 b 
  ON a.Donor=b.Donor 
  AND a.Sire=b.Sire 
  AND a.ET1 > b.ET1
SET a.ET1=b.ET1;
```

With Akina's suggestion, I reckon it would be something like this:

Add a new column and update the new column with the original `ET1` value.

```
ALTER TABLE table1 ADD COLUMN RootET1 INT;
UPDATE table1 SET RootET1=ET1;
```

That would give you something like this:

| ID | Owner | Donor | Sire | ET1 | RootET1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | Jones | Daisy | Bob | 18 | 18 |
| 18 | Owens | Daisy | Bob | 834 | 834 |

After that, you run the same `UPDATE` query above. Now you have the updated `ET1` and original `ET1` value in `RootET1`.

[Here's a fiddle with extended tests](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5850fc7da3549ed8b87890094b421dce)